What is the difference between 叔母 and 伯母? Do they both mean aunt?
I've seen these two used before instead of just おばさん but don't know what the difference is or what they mean exactly. Do they both mean aunt or does one mean something else? Can you use the terms to refer to an aunt (family relative)?

In theory “叔母” is used for the younger sister of a parent, “伯母” for an older one.
